# how to get git short hash in to a variable in Jenkins running on windows 2008

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to get the git short hash in a variable. I tried to set GIT_COMMIT_SHORT variable to run 'git rev-parse --short HEAD' but it didn't work. 
I need this variable to pass to ant build script so the package name include this short hash.

I am running Jenkins on windows 2008 server.

Thanks

Comment: I set up environment variable in jenkins main configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin to load the parameter from a properties file you create that holds the hash.

Echo the result of your `git` command to a formed `key=value` file in your job's workspace and load it with the plugin I mentioned.

I used it for such needs and it's very simple.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
How to write a properties file in windows:

`@for /f "delims=" %l in ('git command') do @echo hash=%l >> hash.properties`

Then, you can load `hash.properties` with the plugin.

Comment: Thank Eldad for a quick reply. what I understand you are suggesting to create a properties file which has short hash and upload it through EnvInject plugin so it can get setup in environment during build time, if this is the case how to create this file on fly on windows?

Comment: Envinject sets variable before git fetch runs, so it won't get set the correct short hash.

Comment: You can run this as a build step, using a **Windows batch command**. About the execution time, you can also add an **Inject environment variable** build step, which runs after SCM commands.

Comment: It gives this error
>FOR /F %i IN ('git.exe rev-parse --short HEAD') DO set COMVER=%i 1>${WORKSPACE}\daddress\buildver.properties >set COMVER=8e18a5c 1>${WORKSPACE}\daddress\buildver.properties The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: 1. When you put this command in Jenkins (or batch file), you need double % sign for the variables. 2. In windows, refer to workspace as %WORKSPACE%.

Answer (score 36):

Probably the simplest way to achieve the result you want would be to use the GIT_REVISION token makro, like this:

```
${GIT_REVISION,length=6}
```

Have a look at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Token+Macro+Plugin for more details.

Hope this helps,
Jan

Comment: This will only work for fields that consumes a TokenMacro, which rules out build steps AFAIK.

Comment: @MattiasBengtsson you're right, but that depends on the build step. It won't work for the shell script step, but should work for the maven one, if I remember correctly

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me in a jenkins pipeline using the git plugin:

```
SHORT_COMMIT = "${GIT_COMMIT[0..7]}"
```

Comment: This works great in declarative pipeline mode:

pipeline { environment { SHORT_COMMIT = "${GIT_COMMIT[0..7]}" } }

Answer (score 14):

I didn't see this answer listed here so thought I'd add it:

```
environment {
  GIT_HASH = GIT_COMMIT.take(8)
}
```

Source: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44449?focusedCommentId=361307&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-361307

Comment: This could be non-unique. git rev-parse produces a hash that's just long enough to be unique.

Comment: Thanks. This works without installing any plugin.

Answer (score 5):

Another possible option for the Blue Ocean Pipeline:

```
pipeline { 
    ...
    environment {
        GIT_COMMIT_SHORT = sh(
                script: "printf \$(git rev-parse --short ${GIT_COMMIT})",
                returnStdout: true
        )
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

On jenkins 2.73 with git plugin this placeholder template works

```
${GIT_REVISION:0:7}
```

I used it with the Delivery pipeline plugin to set the task name.

E.g Building GIT rev. `${GIT_REVISION:0:7}`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it applies but I was searching for a way to do this in a jenkins pipeline. I ended up using this `${GIT_REVISION[0..7]}`

Answer (score 1):

Without any additional plugins you can get commit using the following command in Jenkins script ('Execute Windows batch command' build step):

```
for /f %%i in ('git rev-parse HEAD') do set GITHASH=%%i
```

In command line you should use single `%` instead of `%%`:

```
for /f %%i in ('git rev-parse HEAD') do set GITHASH=%%i
```

Answer (score 0):

Only this work for me

```sh
GIT_SHA_SHORT=`git rev-parse --short=8 ${GIT_COMMIT}`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  return sh(
            script: "printf \$(git rev-parse --short ${env.GIT_COMMIT})",
            returnStdout: true
        ).trim()
        }

        pipeline {
            agent any
            environment {
                SHORT_COMMIT = git_short_commit()

            }
            stages {
                stage('Build') {
                    steps {
                        echo "${SHORT_COMMIT}"
                   }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins with Scripted pipeline:

```
shortCommit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git log -n 1 --pretty=format:'%h'").trim()
```